# How to make nice "auto" numeric format in R dataframe?

Tags: r, formatting, numeric

Is there any options at R or R studio for "auto" representation of numbers to display or export. Like if I have in one column very small number, say 0.000023 so it should be displayed or exported as "2.3e-05", but the other number like 10.23 should be displayed "as is" without changing it to "exponential" format.
>

```
 rf_test
       RfC  RfD_ing RfD_per RfD_derm
2  0.00002       NA 2.0e-03       NA
3  0.10000       NA 1.1e+01       NA
4  0.00500 1.43e-03 1.0e+00 0.100000
5  0.03000       NA 4.0e+00       NA
6  0.00007       NA 2.0e-02 0.000070
7  1.00000 2.86e-05 5.0e-03 0.000060
8  0.00005 1.43e-05 1.4e-01 0.001840
....
```

[image: R console]

Export file looks even more nasty than in RStudio console when exporting like this:

> write.table(rf_test, "rf_test.dat", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, na = "NA")
>   [File with table](https://yadi.sk/d/0EBcdklJODiI4w)

Any suggestions with such formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `format()` function (or, if you want tighter control on how the numbers are displayed, the `formatC()` function)

You could write your own function with an integer division `%/%` operator inside an if/else statement to decide how many decimals the number should have before format should be changed. Something like this:

```
test_func <- function(x){

 res <- 0
 res <- ifelse(x %/% 0.0001 > 0, format(x, scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE), format(x, scientific = TRUE))
 return(res)

}
```

Result:

```
print(rf_test %>% mutate(RfD_per_new = test_func(RfD_per)), n = 26)
# A tibble: 26 x 5
        RfC     RfD_ing   RfD_per  RfD_derm RfD_per_new
      <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      
 1 0.00002  NA           0.002    NA        0.00200    
 2 0.1      NA          11        NA        11.00000   
 3 0.005     0.00143     1         0.1      1.00000    
 4 0.03     NA           4        NA        4.00000    
 5 0.000070 NA           0.02      0.000070 0.02000    
 6 1         0.0000286   0.005     0.00006  0.00500    
 7 0.00005   0.0000143   0.14      0.00184  0.14000    
 8 0.6      NA           0.3      NA        0.30000    
 9 0.00002   0.00000571  0.02      0.016    0.02000    
10 0.00005  NA           0.02      0.0054   0.02000    
11 0.00002   0.0402      0.019     0.012    0.01900    
12 0.0009    0.3         0.3       0.06     0.30000    
13 0.04     NA          NA        NA        NA         
14 0.00003   0.000300    0.000300  0.000123 0.00030    
15 0.00008  NA           0.005    NA        0.00500    
16 0.012    NA           0.005     0.0019   0.00500    
17 0.02     NA           0.005     0.0009   0.00500    
18 0.00002   0.0000571   0.0005    0.00001  0.00050    
19 0.02     NA           0.6      NA        0.60000    
20 0.0004    0.000395    0.0004    0.000008 0.00040    
21 0.0005    0.000143    0.07      0.0049   0.07000    
22 0.0002   NA          NA        NA        NA         
23 0.1      NA           0.0025   NA        0.00250    
24 0.000300  0.0000857   0.000300  0.000021 0.00030    
25 0.00023  NA           0.000070 NA        7.0e-05    
26 0.0005    0.00352     0.0035    0.000525 0.00350
```

Change the number after the integer division operator to your liking to adjust the cutoff point.

Would this work? :)

Comment: Yeah! That's what I was exactly looked for. Thanks a lot for this lesson with detailed  description.